# Unable to connect to AWS GPU Instance from office, but can connect from home

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a EC2 Instance in Amazon - a GPU instance for my work on tensorflow. I'm able to connect to this instance via GIT BASH, winSCP, and through browser aswell(to a jupyter notebook in the instance).

But when i'm connected from my office, i'm not able to connect to it via winscp or SSH. I'm using the SAME LAPTOP. I'm sure that it has something to do with the firewall at my office network, is there a way to resolve this by myself - not reaching out to the office security team?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Security Groups your Instance is attached to? Try looking there first. The Inbound rules will tell you why.

Also most likely you will have ssh port (22) not enabled at your office network. Change your server settings and listen on port 80.

You can do that by 
editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config on your ec2 instance and change Port to 80